# Based on type change object to nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to change nested object to array object by type in javascript.

Based on object key value type if its array/string
change the object to array as shown below in javascript

```
var ob1 = {
  "list": [
    "service",
    "finance",
    "s1.jpg"
  ],
  "info": [
    "details",
    "mail",
    "s2.jpg"
  ]
}

var ob2 = {
   key1: "v1",
   key2: "v2"
}
var result1=this.modifyObject(ob1);
var result2=this.modifyObject(ob2);

function modifyObject(ob){
  const { field, value, id, ...fields } = ob;
  const rest = Object.entries(fields)
  .map(([field, value], id) => ({ field, value, id }));
  const result = [...rest];
  return result;
}
```

Expected Output,

```
// object type value is array
[
 {field: "list", value: ["service","finance"], image: "s1.jpg", id:0},
 {field: "info", value: ["details","mail"], image: "s2.jpg", id:1}
]


// object type value is string
[
 {field:"key1", value:"v1", id:0 },
 {field:"key2", value:"v2", id:1 }
]
```

Comment: Does the image always at the last index? and more than that, how are you getting the name of the property for the image string? in this case `image`, and `id` for the second object.

Comment: @Ele, thanks for reply, yes image is the last index and updated the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the entires of your input object using `Object.entries()` and map each `[key, value]` pair to a new object. You can determine what type of object you want to return by checking whether the second value in the `[key, value]` pair array is an array (ie: checking if the value is an array) by using `Array.isArray()`. If it is an array, you can set the value to be the array, and the image to be the last element (obtained by using `.pop()`, if you don't want to modify the original object you can use slice instead). Otherwise, if the element is not an array, you can return an object which has an `id` property. The `id` property is based on the index of the object from the mapping function.

See example below:

```js
const ob1 = { "list": [ "service", "finance", "s1.jpg" ], "info": [ "details", "mail", "s2.jpg" ] }; const ob2 = { key1: "v1", key2: "v2" };

const modifyObject = obj =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(([field, value], id) => 
    Array.isArray(value) ? {field, value, image: value.pop()}
    : {field, value, id}
  );

const result1 = modifyObject(ob1);
const result2 = modifyObject(ob2);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Note that this `id` property is based on the ordering of how `Object.entries()` obtains the key-value pairs from your object, so it may differ in older browsers (the newest JS spec specifies the ordering of how the [key, value] pairs are obtained using Object.entries, but older browsers may not follow this)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.entries` along with the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to build the desired output.

```js
let ob1 = {  "list": [    "service",    "finance",    "s1.jpg"  ],  "info": [    "details",    "mail",    "s2.jpg"  ]},
    ob2 = {       key1: "v1",       key2: "v2"};

function modifyObject(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [field, value], id) => {
    let [image] = Array.isArray(value) ? value.slice(-1) : [];
    let v = Array.isArray(value) ? value.slice(0, value.length - 1) : value;
    
    return r.concat(Object.assign({id, [field]: v}, image ? {image} : {}));
  }, []);
}

console.log(modifyObject(ob1));
console.log(modifyObject(ob2));
```